# Will Google see rel=nofollow if it is added by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, seo, google-search, nofollow

I'm adding a `rel=nofollow` attribute to links via jQuery after the page load.
Will Google see this attribute? I can't find anything in Google's official documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it useless to add \`nofollow\` using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044245/is-it-useless-to-add-nofollow-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Google processes JavaScript and can index a lot of dynamic content, there's a special behavior when inserting `rel=nofollow` dynamically. It was [tested<sup>[1]</sup>](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) and they came up with this result:

> The nofollow in the DOM did not work (the link was followed, and the page indexed). Why? Because the modification of the a href element in the DOM happened too late: **Google already crawled the link and queued the URL before it executed the JavaScript function that adds the rel=“nofollow” tag.**

The solution is to insert the *whole link with* `rel=nofollow` dynamically:

> However, if the entire *a href* element with nofollow is inserted in the DOM, the nofollow is seen at the same time as the link (and its URL) and is therefore respected.

See section "*5. An Important Example with rel=”nofollow”*" of the provided source.

### Further reading

1. [We Tested How Googlebot Crawls Javascript And Here’s What We Learned](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

Answer (score 1):

The Google spider does process Javascript, so adding the attribute via jQuery should work. I would suggest that you put the `rel="nofollow"` logic in your server-side code though, for guaranteed results.

Answer (score 1):

*Will Google see this attribute?*

In short, No!, that link is already been crawled with google spider.

`rel=nofollow` this attribute should only work if you have set it at serverside when a request is made or you should put it static via keyboard, because after page load it doesn't matter.